# What is the relation between fed rate and yields of the bond?

Tags: fixed-income

We have a metric DV01 of a bond, which is the price change in response to a 1 bp change in yield of this instrument. Yields we can get from solving the equation, so it is a math concept. For bonds with different maturity we can calculate yields and plot a yield curve.

But how yield depends on the key rate (fed rate)? What is the relation between them? How much do they differ in terms of basis points?

Comment: Short maturity Treasury yields have a very high historical correlation with the Fed Funds rate (like 0.99 for yield levels). The correlation is a bit weaker for longer maturities and for corporate bonds but still reasonably large. Understanding this correlation is perhaps more of an economics than a quant finance question.

Comment: BTW it is not clear that the Fed Funds Rate is the key rate any longer. Under the procedures the Fed has followed since about 2010, the IOER (Interest on Excess Reserves) rate is the key rate, and the Fed Funds market plays a lesser role.